# How to put a dynamic placeholder in a textbox for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a textbox with a placeholder, but I don't know how to have a dynamic placeholder depending of the app language.

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="{dynamic value}" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" ></TextBox>
```

How can I put a dynamic value here from the Resources.resw file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Uid` to your `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBox x:Uid="TextBox"/>
```

And then add following key with localized value to your localization resource files:

```
TextBox.PlaceholderText
```

And then depending on phone's region and language settings proper value will be insert as `PlaceholderText` to yout `TextBlock`.

Comment: the text.PlaceholderText generate me an error : Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException Informations WinRT : Unable to resolve property '%1' while processing properties for Uid '%0'. [Line: 39 Position: 109]

Comment: try to use 'YourTextBlockUid.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.PlaceholderText' as Key value in Resources/

Comment: Are you sure you added key-value pair for PlaceholterText in every resource file you have in project?

Comment: @LaurentRussier, sorry, I had mistake in my answer. I defined TextBlock in XAML instead of TextBox. If you had copy it, than it might be the cause of Exception in first place.

Comment: No I let the Texbox, it's the "text.PlaceholderText" that it causing issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72155/discussion-between-khamitimur-and-laurent-russier).